# How to create Text Area and Datepicker using Fulltable?

Tags: jquery

I need your help. I want to create TextArea in the HTML Table using FullTable. Can you help me?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(
        function () {
            $("#my-table").FullTable({
                "alwaysCreating": true,
                "selectable": false,
                "orderable": true,
                "filterable": true
                "fields": {
                    "name": {
                        "mandatory": true,
                        "errors": {
                            "mandatory": "Name is mandatory"
                        }
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "mandatory": false
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#test-table-add-row").click(function () {
                $("#my-table").FullTable("addRow");
            });
            $("#my-table-get-value").click(function () {
                console.log($("#test-table").FullTable("getData"));
            });
            $("#my-table").FullTable("on", "error", function (errors) {
                for (var error in errors) {
                    error = errors[error];
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
            $("#my-table").FullTable("draw");
        }
    );
</script>
```

I have tried and failed :D
This is my code, please help me. :(

Comment: Hi Fadhil, and welcome to StackOverflow! So that people can better answer your question, can you give more details on what's happening vs. what you expect to happen? Are you getting any errors? Also, it looks like you're referencing an element `#mytable`, but you haven't included any HTML. Can you provide that as well?

Comment: Put a comma after `"filterable": true`. So that it reads:`"filterable": true,`

Comment: Suggest that you change `$("#test-table-add-row").click(function ()` to `$("#my-table-add-row").click(function ()`. Plus, of course, changes to all the respective html `ID` fields.